# Many-To-Many Or Not Many-To-Many

Tags: hibernate, jpa

An entity User is defined as the following:

```
class User{

 enum Role{USER, ADMIN}

 private Set<Role> roles;
 ...
}
```

All implementations I have found so far is implementing the Role as another entity and using many-to-many to connect them. That implementation doesn't seem to be right to me because the role is a set of predefined data. And from the database schema design point of view, there shall be a user table and user role table which contains two columns: user ID, a foreign key, and the role data, and the pair forms a composite key. If using the many-to-many implementation, there would be a user table, a role table, and a cross reference table user-role. Can the first approach be done with Hibernate/JPA?

Comment: if you need to add an another Role, suppose MASTER,  then you will have to  change the column definition of the column of User_Role Table.

Comment: Yes, with the many-to-many approach, but not the other.

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/ElementCollection.html

Comment: Thanks for the info. That works quite well based on my test.